# Unable to enable the experimental features in docker

Tags: docker, configuration

I want to enable the experimental features in docker and have found this:
https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/README.md

while I have the following:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
        "experimental": true
}
```

But I still get:

```
$ docker version -f '{{.Server.Experimental}}'
false
```

and I'm wondering why??

This is with `Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c` on an `Ubuntu 16.04` box

Comment: Have you restarted docker or your computer? Docker will probably require a restart to enable experimental features.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart the daemon after creating the file?

```sh
systemctl restart docker
```

Or perhaps:

```sh
service docker restart
```

You may need to `sudo` the command